# Пунктуация в замысловатом сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, сложное-предложение

Уважаемые знатоки! Какие знаки препинания вы поставили бы вместо цифр в этом загадочном предложении?

Сердце, расположенное посреди груди, судорожно билось(1) и потерять сознание не получалось(2) по всему выходило, что ждет молодого мага медленная и мучительная смерть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 – запятая (закрывается часть);

2 – тире (т.к. из первой части следует вторая).

Я думаю, что это предложение построено так, что имеет в себе своеобразный "детерминант", относящийся к двум частям: первые две части связаны с "по всему" несмотря на грамматическое несоответствие. А между частями запятая, потому что об однородном подчинении речи не идет (часть с детерминантом соединяется БСС).

Comment: Вот именно, с детерминантом, да еще и своеобразным! Я запомню! Теперь есть ответ. Не все же ссылаться на интуицию.

Comment: @ Станислав Терляков  Хотелось бы увидеть само предложение, то есть расстановку знаков препинания в нем (по описанию это не очень ясно).   А также определение структуры предложения, как это принято при проведении грамматического анализа. (Детерминант - это термин, относящийся к простому предложению, здесь его надо назвать как-то по-другому).

Comment: @ Jasmin Вы задались целью прокомментировать все мои ответы? Окей. Расстановку я считаю очевидной из своего комментария, и автор вопроса с этим вроде согласен. Указал, на что следует заменить цифры. Именно структуру я и привел, могу уточнить.

Comment: Четыре части, 1 со 2 связаны СС и однородны,  обе связаны с 3 БСС, и 4 часть присоединена к 3 ПС.

Comment: Все ВАШИ ответы?  Тогда извините, пожалуйста, что так совпало. Я вообще-то  не авторов комментирую, а именно ответы, если они мне непонятны. Неужели вам трудно было скопировать предложение и расставить знаки, чтобы всё было наглядно.   И вот вопросы, которые так и остались неясными. Почему вы ставите запятую 1, если два первых предложения  связывает  общая вторая часть? (Кстати, я, кажется, вспомнила. Это же Вы присоединяете, а не соединяете придаточные).  В этом сложном предложении четыре простых, но они объединены в два блока, причем второй блок является СПП с придаточным изъяснительным

Comment: @ Jasmin, прошу прощения, зря насчет "всех ответов". Погорячился. А вот придаточные можно и "присоединять", насколько я помню. Насчет запятой Вы правы: все же первые две части однородны. Лучше ее не ставить, хотя интонационно пауза там есть. Наверное, эта пауза связана не с пунктуацией, а с особенностями речи: фраза произносится не на одном дыхании. Убирать тире, как в одном из вариантов в Вашем ответе, мне кажется нелогичным, потому что значение следствия теряется. Наверное, правильным будет поставить тире на месте 2 и не ставить знак в позиции 1.

Answer (score 2):

**Сердце, расположенное посреди груди, судорожно билось,  и потерять сознание не получалось; по всему выходило, что ждет молодого мага медленная и мучительная смерть.**

В первой части сложного предложения обособленный оборот мешает объединению двух предложений с сочинительной связью в одну фразу,  поэтому запятая ставится.

Но если убрать оборот, то такое объединение возможно; в этом случае бессоюзную связь со второй частью предложения можно считать общим элементом (запятая перед союзом И не ставится).

**Сердце судорожно билось и потерять сознание не получалось ― по всему выходило, что ждет молодого мага медленная и мучительная смерть.**

Comment: Что мешает поставить тире в исходном тексте?

Comment: @ Jasmin Ваша подсказка очень кстати.)))

Comment: @ М_Г  А вы что-нибудь поняли про "своеобразный детерминант"?  Мне кажется. что по "по всему"  имеет значение "поэтому", то есть это наречие со значением следствия. Если мы ставим тире (обозначаем это общее следствие), то запятые перед союзом И не надо ставить и произносить первую часть следует в одну фразу, но этому мешает обособленный оборот, его же тоже следует выделять интонационно. Вот в чем трудность решения.

Comment: Оставим "своеобразный детерминант" автору этого термина:)). Формальные трудности понимаю, но интуитивно поставил бы (1)запятую, (2) тире (или зпт+тире).

Comment: Тире обозначает следствие двух первых предложений, тогда запятую (1) не надо ставить.